# Reconnect to existing Red Hat session

Tags: redhat, remote-access, remote-desktop

I am trying to connect to my Red hat desktop (v 7.6 Maipo) machine using windows rdp program, but it gives me a separate session through RDP vs the one that is active using red hat desktop machine(when i login physically on the machine).

How can I configure Red Hat so that even RDP also connects to a previously available session. I have tried changing /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini to below and restarting rdp services but that doesnt help either.

```
name=Xrdp
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5912
```